# Add free space to ubuntu home

Tags: partitioning, disk, debian

I have this disk setup:

[image]

Where Partition 3 is windows installed and I reduced its size by 31GB, which is the new free space (Espacio Libre 31GB). Now, I need to add those 31GB to Partition 7, but I dont find any way. I have tried with a bootable USB ubuntu but it needs to install a new Ubuntu when I can't uninstall the current one. In windows I would use a program to just move the free 31GB space to the partition I want, clic OK and it's done!. But here in Ubuntu is blocked, neither I find an alternative on the internet.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Partitions can only be expanded to their neighbor blocks… so first move partitions 5 and 6 after 3 so the free space is next to 7 then you can expand 7 in the free space.

Comment: Use The Gparted or the Disks applications from a live USB in the **try Ubuntu** mode.